# What is a Swap Server (DHCP option 16)?

Tags: dhcp

While configuring DHCP options, I could see an option with number 16. It says "Swap Server". I have no idea about it and I couldn't find any help from the Internet.

Comment: This might be a great question on https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swap server option gives the IP address of a server that provides a swap space
service (that is, a service such as providing swap storage through the network for a
diskless workstation) for the client.

Source - http://alexeykr.noip.me/The%20DHCP%20Handbook.pdf

Comment: Dead link, but Internet Archive has a snapshot from 2018 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180219175447/https://alexeykr.noip.me/The%20DHCP%20Handbook.pdf)